# where clause based on conditions

Tags: sql

I have a query where I match a column. The value to be matched may be null or not null (some value exists). The problem arises when the matching takes place. In case value is present the matching like

```
table.column = somevalue
```

works fine, but in case the value is null, then the matching needs to be done as

```
table.column is null
```

Is there some way that I can choose the condition being used in the WHERE clause based on the value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about ORing your `WHERE` clause?

```
SELECT
*
FROM table
WHERE ((table.column = 123) AND table.column IS NOT NULL))
OR    (table.column IS NULL)
```

Comment: I think, `AND table.column IS NOT NULL` is redundant. If `table.column` is equal to 123 then it's definitely not NULL, no need to verify that. And when it is NULL it cannot match 123, so again, no need to additionally check whether it is NOT NULL.

Comment: You are right, the code is not optimal at all. I wrote it that way so it is clearer for Rohan.

Comment: currently I am using it as (table.column = 123 or table.column is null ). The problem I was facing is when the value in the column is null then equating it as  "table.column = null" rejects the record, even if the column has null value. Only using it as "table.column IS NULL" works.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CASE statement, e.g.:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN mycol IS NULL
      THEN 'it is null'
    WHEN mycol = 'foo'
      THEN 'it is foo'
    ELSE 'it is something else'
  END AS col
FROM mytable;
```

(Note: I don't know what DB you are using, so "IS NULL", "ISNULL", "ISNULL()" might be needed above)

Comment: Is it possible to use CASE statements in where clause?

Comment: Yup, you just need to phrase it so it returns `TRUE`/`FALSE`, e.g.: `WHEN CASE WHEN mycol IS NULL THEN TRUE WHEN MYCOL = 'foo' THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS COL;`

Comment: But wait, are you matching two columns from *two different tables*? If so, then you need a `LEFT JOIN` .. I can elaborate if that is what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Check the MySQL [Control Flow functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try using ISNULL(somevalue, 0). Provided that your "somevalue" table.column does not have 0 is a valid value. Instead of 0 you may use any string/number that will never appear as a valid value in table.column

Answer (score 1):

In ms sql you could do

```
      declare @match int
      select * from tbl where coalesce(tblValue, @match) = @match
```

That way you will compare @match with itself when tblValue is null.

Of course you can eliminate the parameter if it is null by switching the matching

```
      select * from tbl where tblValue = coalesce(@match, tblValue)
```

but the latter query may cause the query optimizer to neglect indexes on tblValue, so you should check the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

I used decode and case statement to solve this problem
This has been done in oracle.

```
    AND DECODE(TSBI.SHIP_TRAIL_STATUS, 
               'L', 
               'TRUE', 
               'C', 
               (SELECT CASE 
                    WHEN TSBI.UPD_ON + 10 >= SYSDATE THEN 
                         'TRUE' 
                     ELSE 
                          'FALSE' 
                      END 
                FROM DUAL)) = 'TRUE'
```

In this condition I have checked the SHIP_TRAIL_STATUS. In case it returns 'L' the decode function returns TRUE. In case it returns 'C' the decode checks the UPD_ON value. Accordingly this CASE statement return TRUE or FALSE.